# Working with Aspose on a Template (word) with iterations

Tags: .net, ms-word, aspose

I'm trying to set up a Word document. In this document i want to replicate my questionnaires. So i need to iterate for all my categories, then for my questions and then for the answers. If it's possible I don't want to configure  everything in my code (font and size and so on) because I have a template.

My way to solve this would be to copy the template head for each category and replace some text with the category name. After it I would work the same way for the questions and the answers (specific variable of course)

My problem is i don't find a way to mark my template head so I can copy it.  The other problem is I don't know how to replace the copied placeholder, where I want to set my category name.

If someone can help me I would really appreciate it.

ps: in the aspose forum is like every link down and this is frustrating.

Comment: You can use Range.Replace method to find the text and replace it with new text. You can implement IReplacingCallback interface if you want to have your own custom method called during a find and replace operation. Please share your input and expected output documents. I will then share the code example according to your requirement. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: I have used Range.Replace for the text i bookmarked so it cant happen that i change something unexpected.
Most of my work I try to do with the default methods because for me its easier to understand. ^^ 
Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, with your help. I will not post the documents because there are mainly written in German. 
I used a template doc and an output doc. Declared bookmarks in my template Doc, to define wich part i want to copy. Get the bookmarks i needed from the template doc and copied into the output doc.

To copy the bookmarks i used following code:

```
private void AppendBookmarkedText(NodeImporter importer, Bookmark srcBookmark, CompositeNode dstNode)

{

// This is the paragraph that contains the beginning of the bookmark.

Paragraph startPara = srcBookmark.BookmarkStart.ParentNode as Paragraph;

// This is the paragraph that contains the end of the bookmark.

Paragraph endPara = srcBookmark.BookmarkEnd.ParentNode as Paragraph;

if ((startPara == null) || (endPara == null))

throw new InvalidOperationException("Parent of the bookmark start or end is not a paragraph, cannot handle this scenario yet.");

// Limit ourselves to a reasonably simple scenario.

if (startPara.ParentNode != endPara.ParentNode)

throw new InvalidOperationException("Start and end paragraphs have different parents, cannot handle this scenario yet.");

// We want to copy all paragraphs from the start paragraph up to (and including) the end paragraph,

// therefore the node at which we stop is one after the end paragraph.

Node endNode = endPara.NextSibling;

// This is the loop to go through all paragraph-level nodes in the bookmark.

for (Node curNode = startPara; curNode != endNode; curNode = curNode.NextSibling)

{

// This creates a copy of the current node and imports it (makes it valid) in the context

// of the destination document. Importing means adjusting styles and list identifiers correctly.

Node newNode = importer.ImportNode(curNode, true);

// Now we simply append the new node to the destination.

dstNode.AppendChild(newNode);

}
```

yep, it's just copied from this aspose website: https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/post/65476.aspx?Ajax_CallBack=true

After i was able to copy content from template doc and past it in the output doc, it was easy to work with it.
I only did these few lines in every loop:

```
            CompositeNode dstNode = myOutDoc.LastSection.Body;
            Bookmark mySpecialBookmark= myTemplate.Range.Bookmarks["mySpecialBookmark"]; 

            mySpecialBookmark.Text = mySpecialBookmark.Text.Replace("<myChangingWord>", myObj.newWord);
            AppendBookmarkedText(importer, mySpecialBookmark, dstNode);
            mySpecialBookmark.Text = mySpecialBookmark.Text.Replace(myObj.newWord, "<myChangingWord>");
```

For explain I used to set my replaced text in '<>' to clarify in my document which Text is for Placeholding something an wich is not.

Thanks for your help anyways :) 
(and i hope you understand what i have written down, i know my English is the worst)

Comment: Sure, I can read it (kann auch Deutsch lesen <g>). I'm not familiar with Aspose and I didn't notice, as I recall, that you're not using a VB-language - my apologies. The only thing I don't understand is why you didn't mark your answer as "the answer"? You're allowed (even encouraged) to do that on Stack Overflow...

Comment: There is no problem with translate from VB to C# (which i used).
I just need a push in the right direction. 

Well i dont know dont like to mark my own answers its like, give a like to your own posts :D

Comment: It's not so much as "giving a like" as indicating to others who may be searching for an answer that this is what best solved the problem in your Question. On StackOverflow it's also correct to vote up any posts you find helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copying something in a template as part of an iteration, the better approach would be to create a BuildingBlock in the template and insert that, as needed. You'd create the BuildingBlock as an end-user, saving it in the template.

Write some placeholder text in the template and bookmark it as the target for inserting the BuildingBlock.

You then create a *new document* from the template and work with that, so that the template is not changed:

```
 Dim wdDoc as Word.Document = WordApplication.Documents.Add stringTemplatePath
Dim BookmarkTarget as Word.Bookmark = wdDoc.Bookmarks(BookmarkName)
```

Insert a BuildingBlock using the Insert method:

```
WordApplication.Templates( pathToTemplateFile) _
    .BuildingBlockEntries(stringBuidlingBlockName).Insert(Where:=BookmarkTarget.Range, RichText:=True)
```

In order to mark something in the BuildingBlock that you want to target for data input you have two choices: Bookmark or ContentControl. Either will work for the requirement "replace the copied placeholder, where I want to set my category name". All things being equal, I'd usually choose a Bookmark for this when working with the Interop. It will be deleted automatically when you write text to it. For example:

```
 wdDoc.Bookmarks(Bookmark2Name).Range.Text = stringCategoryInfo
```

Comment: I have to use aspose and i think "WordApplication" is a class from the word api (i am not exactly sure but i didnt found it).